# Consecutive onscreenclick events in Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My aim is to call a series of functions (consecutively), each with two arguments, upon left-clicking the screen/canvas, automatically supplied with the coordinates of the point clicked.

My goal is for these to be sequential, not all at once with one click. So, click the screen, call function 1, click the screen again (with new coordinates), call function 2 with new coordinates supplied etc.

Here's what I have tried:

```
from turtle import *

def f(x, y):
     goto(x, -y) 

def g(x, y):
     goto(-x, y)

def main():
     onscreenclick(f)
     onscreenclick(g)

main()
```

After [reading through the literature](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.onscreenclick) on 'onclick', 'onscreenclick', I gather it is related to whether you put 'True','False' or 'None' for the third argument.

After trying various combinations of these, all it does is either call all of them upon first click or just call the last one.

If anyone knows of anywhere I can find a more detailed explanation of mouse click events in Python, especially with Turtle graphics I would be most grateful. Or if you can answer the question yourself of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you want different functions on each click, try the following:

```
from turtle import *

def f(x, y):
    goto(x, -y) 
    onscreenclick(g)  # what happens next time

def g(x, y):
    goto(-x, y)
    onscreenclick(f)  # what happens next time

def main():
    onscreenclick(f)

main()

mainloop()
```

You should be able to repeatedly click and see the behavior alternating between the two functions.

Your understanding of the third argument to `onscreenclick()` was correct, you can either *replace* existing event handling or you can *augment* it, but it's not set up to alternate it.